# Unity:Detecting collision switch while maintaining game functionality

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have created a random generator for a prefab called "Tunnel". Whenever i collide with a tunnel prefab, i wish to keep the game running. If i am no longer colliding with a tunnel i wish the game to stop.

The game works fine for the first tunnel, but when i reach the end of the first tunnel (start of the second - they overlap), my "OnTriggerExit2D" function stops the game.

Is there a way to tell my "OnTriggerExit2D" to check if i'm colliding with a different tunnel?

Here's my code:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
     {
         Debug.Log (other.gameObject.tag);
         if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("LeftTunnel")) {
             touchRef.onTunnelL = true;
         }
         if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("RightTunnel")) {

             touchRef.onTunnelR = true;
         } 

     }

     void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
     {
         if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("LeftTunnel"))
         {
             touchRef.OnTriggerExit2Dchild();
             touchRef.onTunnelL = false;
         }

         if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("RightTunnel"))
         {
             touchRef.OnTriggerExit2Dchild();
             touchRef.onTunnelR = false;
         }
     }
```

thanks!

Comment: Wouldnt it be better to have the object that the player hits tell the player what they are hitting? This allows you to have your tunnels affect your player and not have a massive if contraption function. You can decouple each behavior to a seperate public function.

Comment: okay, so if i'm getting this right, i should try adding to each Tunnel's code a reference to the finger touching it - saying this specific finger is touching this specific tunnel. or something? :)

Answer (score 0):

So, after consulting with some people I decided to change the whole mechanism to work with ray casting and it works great now.

Here's the code for anyone in the future (I call cast function on Update):

```
void Cast()                                                                                                                                        
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i)
    {
        Vector2 test = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(i).position);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(test, (Input.GetTouch(i).position));
        Vector2 touchPos = new Vector2(test.x, test.y);
        onLeft(touchPos);
        onRight(touchPos);

    }
}
void onLeft(Vector2 touchPos){
    Collider2D tempL;
    if (tempL = Physics2D.OverlapPoint (touchPos)) {
        if(tempL.CompareTag("LeftTunnel")){
        Debug.Log ("Hit Left tunnel");
        onTunnelL = true;
        }
    }
    else{
        onTunnelL = false;
    }
}
void onRight(Vector2 touchPos){
    Collider2D tempR;
    if (tempR = Physics2D.OverlapPoint (touchPos)) {
        if(tempR.CompareTag("RightTunnel")){
            Debug.Log ("Hit Right tunnel");
            onTunnelR = true;
        }
    }
    else{
        onTunnelR = false;
    }
}
```